# What does "That makes four" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[*This is falling*](https://novelfreereadonline.com/this-is-falling/page-57-1955343)

The girl begged the male character. He promised her.

> I nod yes, and she squeals—, one of those girly noises I didn’t think
>   she was capable of—, she scoots closely to me and kisses my cheek.
>   **That makes four**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that this was the fourth occurrence of something.

Maybe it was the fourth time a girl had kissed him. Maybe it was the fourth time this particular girl had kissed him. Maybe it was the fourth surprising thing that happened to him that day or that week.

What particular event and three previous events combine to "make four" should be revealed by the context.

**Edit**

Following your link and reading back to the previous page, you'll find the section in question begins with,

> I have kissed her exactly three times so far, and she hasn’t protested a single one.

So the kiss described on page 57, combined with the three previous kisses, "make four".